# How does Django Admin Authentication work?

Tags: python, django

I've been looking at the codes for Django's Admin app to identify how they perform blanket authentication check on the user for all of its views without any idea how it was done (Django beginner here).

For example, in Admin's `sites.py` there is the `index` view that that isn't called at all if the user is not authenticated. I'm aware that there is some pre-processing that occurs which results in `login` being called instead but I'm unable to identify the method that calls `login`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how a request flows for the Admin app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the relevant file -- [django/contrib/admin/sites.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/sites.py). In particular, look at the `admin_view` decorator on line 170 (this is where `login` is called) and the `wrap` decorator on line 211, the latter of which is applied on each view of the `urlpatterns` on line 217. (It's similar to how the `login_required` decorator from `django.contrib.auth` works).

Basically, every view is wrapped in a decorator that checks whether the user can access the admin site (line 147, `request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff` -- note that if the user is not logged in, then `request.user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser`, for which `is_active` and `is_staff` are always `False`), and displays the `login` view if not.

Comment: Right - so when the URLs are retrieved, they are automatically wrapped with `admin_view` which automatically performs the check before the actual view is called. Thanks!